# Converting VIIRS DNB image pixel value into DN value by overlapping year(2013) based on DMSP-OLS image

Tags: viirs

I want to analyze Nighttime data. So i have collected DMSP image 1992-2013 and VIIRS image 2013-2022. But the pixel value is different for DMSP and VIIRS image. So i used 2013 images for coverting VIIRS image pixel value into DMSP pixel by establishing BiDose Response formula. I have achieved some coefficient from that formula. Can i use this coefficient to predict pixel value of VIIRS image after 2014-2022?